# Write gRPC client for Hyperledger fabric V1.0

Tags: grpc, hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric, grpc-java

Hyperledger Fabric v1.0 provides basic API using Protocol Buffers over gRPC for applications to interact with the blockchain network.

I have seen many examples using CLI commands, but hard to find any GO/JAVA client who are communicating with Blockchain using gRPC. Earlier it was supporting REST APIs but seem like they stopped support for it in newly released V1.0 version[Documention](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1R5RtIBMW9fZpli37E5Li5_Q9ve3BnQ4q3gWmGZj6Sv4/edit#heading=h.z6ne0og04bp5).

If anyone has any idea about how to write gRPC client for fabric client in GO/Java language, please help.

Answer (score 1):

I just run the example in v1.0 doc OK.

curl -L https://raw.githubusercontent.com/hyperledger/fabric/master/examples/sfhackfest/sfhackfest.tar.gz -o sfhackfest.tar.gz 2> /dev/null;  tar -xvf sfhackfest.tar.gz

curl -OOOOOO https://raw.githubusercontent.com/hyperledger/fabric-sdk-node/v1.0-alpha/examples/balance-transfer/{config.json,deploy.js,helper.js,invoke.js,query.js,package.json}

This example using node.js interact with peers.

Thus, I will read these javascripts. Maybe I can find some track of HTTP GET/POST rest API.